# Hosting server's preview URL doesn't allow me to access /admin control panel

Tags: url, admin, preview

I'm running craft 3. I just switched my hosting provider. They do preview URL's to the domains different than what I had before. The preview looks like this: https://(ip address):8090/preview/domain.com/

Problem is if I try to go to https://(ip address):8090/preview/domain.com/admin it doesn't see the control panel.

Is there a way to make this work in preview mode? I can cheat it by updating my local hosts file, but I need my client to be able to access this easily to make updates before going live.